# Spring security single sign on

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, single-sign-on

I'm using Spring-Boot and annotation based Spring-Security and I would like to use another site as one of my authentication providers.

I search on google but not getting any proper example or related solutions.

Let me know how can I implement Single sign on for 2 different application.

Please Guide.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Jasig CAS to implement SSO and it is supported by Spring Security: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/cas.html

Comment: Hi ike3 , thanks for answer but I already see this solution. I want to solution in spring boot and spirng security without using any third party lib.

Comment: Which server are your apps hosted on? Your could use SSO provided by the server, such as Tomcat's org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn

Comment: My apps hosted on apache tomcat. one app is host on localhost:8080 and another app is host on localhost:9090

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@EnableOAuth2Sso` on your spring-boot application set some properties: client id, client secret, token endpoint for your oauth2 server, etc.

This tutorial is for an angularJS client on spring-boot but the server side is similar: https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v